# How to provide format in latex

Tags: formatting, typography

How to give the format of ZOZZLE as follows in latex?
(please disregards to blue highlight, it is due to selection of mouse)

[image]

Comment: You mean with `\textsc{}`?

Comment: Without doubt \textsc{Zozzle} is the short and right answer, but note that in fonts without small caps ([aurical](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/aurical/), for example), you always can obtain a nearly result with Z{\scriptsize ozzle}.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `Zozzle` more than once or twice it is good practice to define a macro for it. In his book Bringhurst advises to space out small caps a little. This can easily be done using the `microtype` package. To match the font of your screenshot I loaded `newtxtext`.

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[tracking=smallcaps]{microtype}
\newcommand*\zozzle{\textsc{Zozzle}}
\begin{document}
\begin{description}
\item[Accuracy:] Figure~\ref{fig:whatever} shows the overall classification
accuracy of \zozzle\ when evaluated using our malicious
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

> [image]